# Pre-trained CNN models for high resolution images

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I am trying to fine-tune a model with my dataset using Keras. However instead of using the default input shape (224 x 224 x 3) for almost all of the available models, I want to set the input shape as 900 x 1200 x 3 . Because my dataset consists of images ranging between 900x1200 pixels to even 3024 x 4032 pixels, all of them with aspect ratio of 3:4.

I have done some research, but could not find any solid information about how to find a pre-trained model that was trained with high resolution images, rather than 224x244 pixels images. So my question is;

- How can I obtain a pre-trained model, preferably trained on ImageNet dataset, with high input dimensions?
- If it is not possible to find such a model, would it be okay to fine-tune the models like VGG16, MobileNet with input size changed to 900 x 1200 x 3?